# firebase recycler view malfunctions on different version of android

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

firebase **recyclerview** responds after **two to three swipes on screen** on android **7(noughat)** and above and works properly on the version below 7(marshmallow & lollipop).

I am using firebase recyclerview  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'

my current version of firebase-ui-database:2.3.0' and other compile dependencies with version 11.0.4

I had tried to upgrade my project to new firebase ui version 3.x too ,but the problem persisted.

i am not able to figure it out that whether it is a design error in the layout xml file, which comes on version above 6 or it is some code related issue with recycler adapter.

I don't know whether it is related to it or not but in warning section, it shows

> W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input
>   event receiver has already been disposed.

the error log shows this

> 12-24 11:32:49.478 2084-18433/? E/H264SwENC: [H264SwEnc SetParam] Force Encode I-frame
>   12-24 11:32:51.377 2031-2406/? E/VT: [SRV] [VT THREAD] [VT_Bind] des = volte_imsvt1 Fail to connect . retry count: 2732
>   12-24 11:32:51.864 3366-5393/? E/NetworkScheduler: ignoring stale queue check message
>   12-24 11:32:52.261 2084-18433/? E/H264SwENC: [H264SwEnc SetParam] Force Encode I-frame
>   12-24 11:32:53.420 2177-2271/? E/MAL-RDS:  (  rds_ru_3gpp_status_ind, 1753) [RDS-E][RU][EVENT_RU_DM_3GPP_STATUS_IND] Invalid u43gpp_status:0x8
>   12-24 11:32:54.241 2084-18433/? E/H264SwENC: [H264SwEnc SetParam] Force Encode I-frame

please help me with it

Comment: Post the error log

Answer (score 0):

With this version of 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0' you probably need to use this version of Firebase core and any other Firebase that you use:

'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'

Make sure all Firebase libraries are the same version.